# momentjs subtract return the same value

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i am parsing a date from a time value looks like 1256 formats to HHmm :

```
let parsedTime = moment(time, "HHmm");
console.log(parsedTime)
//moment("2017-11-07T12:56:00.000") 


console.log(parsedTime.subtract(3, 'hours'))
//moment("2017-11-07T12:56:00.000")
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: i tried this also but same value  moment(time, "HHmm").subtract(3, 'hours')

Comment: what is value of `time` here

Comment: the value of time is 1256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you were observing the moment object which has a property `_i` which tells you the initial value.  The actual value can be seen with [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```js
let time = moment("1256", "HHmm");
console.log(time.format())
//moment("2017-11-07T12:56:00.000")


console.log(time.subtract(3, 'hours').format())
//moment("2017-11-07T9:56:00.000")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you observe the `_d` property from the returned object in the console, it holds the modified value after the subtraction .

```
let time = '1256';
let parsedTime = moment(time, "HHmm");
console.log(parsedTime)
/* Object 
 { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "1256", _f: "HHmm", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2017-11-08T07:26:00.000Z, _isValid: true } */


console.log(parsedTime.subtract(3, 'hours'));

/* Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "1256", _f: "HHmm", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2017-11-08T04:26:00.000Z, _isValid: true } */
```